# Does the Dishonored iOS game interact with the main game?

Tags: ios, dishonored

I was wondering if the mobile *Dishonored: Rat Assassin* (a bloody and not PETA-approved *Fruit Ninja*-clone) interacted with the main release of the game. If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Dishonored [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dishonored_(video_game)#Release)

> A spin-off iOS game, Dishonored: Rat Assassin, was developed by
>   Bethesda Softworks and released on August 30, 2012 for free. The game
>   requires players to use a knife and crossbow to kill rats while
>   avoiding bombs. A set of three animated videos, titled Tales from
>   Dunwall, serving as a prequel to the game story were released in
>   September 2012. The videos show the discovery of whale oil fuel,
>   the Outsider granting his mark to a small boy in search of
>   revenge, and Piero creating Corvo's mask.

Comment: These three videos can be viewed in their entirety on the official Bethesda Softworks youtube channel   
[Episode 1- The Awakening](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hD4BcrDJdo)     
[Episode 2- The Hand that Feeds](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Va8Ez__QNoE)   
[Episode 3- In the Mind of Madness](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIgrvjkaSP8)